# PHP: Returning 'hash' to Ruby API as GET

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I'm working with an API where I need to provide parameters via **GET** in order to get a response.

I'm working with PHP.

This is what the API documentation says:

> **Arguments**
>
> ```
> {
>     'answers': { 'q0':2, 'q1':2, 'q2':1 }
> }
> ```
>
> answers (required), **hash**
>
> **Hash** describing the answers.

I know that the API itself is written in Ruby, so I'm *assuming* that 'hash' would translate to 'associative array' in PHP context (please correct me if you think I'm wrong here -- I don't know Ruby, but this is where research has lead me).

That said, this what I've tried so far (with no success -- I'm really not quite sure how to tackle this):

**My (terribly broken) code:**

```
$answers = array('q0' => 1,
            'q1' => 2,
            'q2' => 3,
            'q3' => 0,
            'q4' => 2,
            'q5' => 1,
            'q6' => 0
            );

$url = "https://myapiurl.com?answers=" . $answers;

$session = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authentication: Token token=' . $token . ', Content-Type:application/json'));
curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);
curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, '3');

$response = curl_exec($session);

curl_close($session);

var_dump($response);
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try subscript operator style URL parameters for nested parameters in GET requests. Eg:

`"https://myapiurl.com?answers[q0]=1&answers[q1]=2"` etc.

At least it worked on sinatra server, so it should also work for rails server.

Comment: That did it! Thanks so much.